# Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'login' available as request attribute

Tags: spring

i dnt understand the problem here ... i am creating binding object by hitting the ds.xml with index.jsp and given same name commandName and attribute name same ... but still it says bean name is not available .. and one more thing is der any diff in modelattribute and commandName ..

```
 @Controller
@RequestMapping("/login")
public class LoginController {


@Autowired
public Validator validator;

public void setValidator(Validator validator) {
    this.validator = validator;
}

@InitBinder
public void bindvalidator(WebDataBinder web){
    web.setValidator(validator);

}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showForm(ModelMap map) {
    System.out.println("*************************");

    map.addAttribute("login", new LoginDTO());

    return "login";
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String login(@Valid LoginDTO logindetails,BindingResult bindingResult) {
      if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {               
          return "login";           
          } 
      else {               

          return "result";            
          }
}
}
```

Login.jsp

```
    <%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>Spring MVC Example</title>
</head>
<body>


    <form:form method ="POST" action="login.do"  commandName="login">

username:<form:input path="username" /><form:errors path="username"/>

     Password:<form:password path="password"/><form:errors path="password"/>

    <input type="submit" value="Login" />
    </form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good.

Are you accessing directly the JSP (http://localhost:[xxx]/MyProject/Login.jsp) o through the controller (http://localhost:[xxx]/MyProject/login.do)?

Comment: issue is nt dat .. it is saying binding object is nt formed ...map.addAttribute("login", new LoginDTO());
 is nt sending the attribute details in this form and it is nt catched by commandName object 
 ... there is something problem .. i still dnt understand what is dat ..

Answer (score 0):

Your jsp uses: 
    method ="POST"  commandName="login"
but your controller has:
    @RequestMapping("/login")
this should be:
    @PostMapping("/login")